session management error ( Not able to logout)
I am not able to logout. everytime when i click on logout it gives me methond not allowed error with code 405.
Backend.py This is my backend file

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_session import Session
import logging
import joblib
import bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'b53188295937de88acf7c26a8c0a9de11c915d7e1defe86ded74dbd07ef0c5e6'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb+srv://jg581261:tubeligh@stressdetector.zkbcqby.mongodb.net/StressDetector?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=StressDetector'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
Session(app)

mongo = PyMongo(app)

try:
    mongo.cx.server_info()
    print("Connected to MongoDB successfully")
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to connect to MongoDB", e)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, origins=["http://localhost:3000"], methods=["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"])

class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        return f"{record.levelname}: {record.message}"

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(CustomFormatter())
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('pymongo').setLevel(logging.ERROR)

class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, user_id, username, password):
        self.id = user_id
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    user = mongo.db.users.find_one({"_id": user_id})
    if user:
        return User(str(user['_id']), user['username'], user['password'])
    return None

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    data = request.json
    username = data['username']
    password = data['password']
    hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
    try:
        user_id = mongo.db.users.insert_one({'username': username, 'password': hashed_password}).inserted_id
        app.logger.info(f"POST /register 201: User {username} registered with id {user_id}")
        return jsonify({"message": "User registered", "user_id": str(user_id)}), 201
    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error(f"POST /register 500: Error during registration: {e}")
        return jsonify({"message": "Registration failed", "error": str(e)}), 500

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    data = request.json
    try:
        user = mongo.db.users.find_one({"username": data['username']})
        if user and bcrypt.checkpw(data['password'].encode('utf-8'), user['password']):
            user_obj = User(str(user['_id']), user['username'], user['password'])
            login_user(user_obj)
            session.clear()  # Clear any existing session data
            session['user_id'] = str(user['_id'])  # Only set session data after successful login
            app.logger.info("POST /login 200: User logged in")
            return jsonify({"message": "Logged in", "session_status": "Session Active"}), 200
        app.logger.warning("POST /login 401: Invalid credentials")
        return jsonify({"message": "Invalid credentials"}), 401
    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error(f"POST /login 500: Error during login: {e}")
        return jsonify({"message": "Login failed", "error": str(e)}), 500

@app.route('/session', methods=['GET'])
def check_session():
    user_id = session.get('user_id')
    if user_id:
        app.logger.info(f"GET /session 200: User {user_id} session active")
        return jsonify({"message": "Session active", "user_id": user_id}), 200
    else:
        app.logger.info("GET /session 401: No active session")
        return jsonify({"message": "No active session"}), 401

@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def logout():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        app.logger.info(f"POST /logout: User {current_user.id} is logging out")
        logout_user()
        session.clear()  # Clear session data
        app.logger.info(f"POST /logout 200: User {current_user.id} logged out")
        return jsonify({"message": "Logged out"}), 200
    else:
        app.logger.warning(f"POST /logout 401: User not authenticated")
        return jsonify({"message": "Not authenticated"}), 401

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Navbar.jsx this is the navber where logout functionality is working.
import React from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
import axios from 'axios';
import './navbar.css';

const CustomNavbar = ({ theme, setTheme, isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated, setUsername }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Attempting to logout");
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/logout', {}, { withCredentials: true });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        setUsername('');
        navigate('/login');
        console.log("Logout successful");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Logout failed:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Navbar bg={theme === 'dark' ? 'dark' : 'light'} variant={theme === 'dark' ? 'dark' : 'light'} expand="lg" className="navbar-design">
      <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to="/">Stress Detector</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/">Home</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/about">About</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
        <Nav>
          <Nav.Link onClick={() => setTheme(theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark')}>Toggle Theme</Nav.Link>
          {isAuthenticated ? (
            <NavDropdown title="Profile" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to="/profile">Profile</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/login">Login</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/signup">Signup</Nav.Link>
            </>
          )}
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default CustomNavbar;

app.js this is my app.js code where all the routing i have done
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './Components/Home/home';
import axios from 'axios';
import Login from './Components/Login and Signup/login';
import Signup from './Components/Login and Signup/signup';
import Dashboard from './Components/Dashboard/dashboard';
import CustomNavbar from './Components/Navbar/navbar';
import PrivateRoute from './config/PrivateRoute';
import Logout from './Components/Login and Signup/logout';

const App = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkSession = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/session', { withCredentials: true });
        if (response.status === 200 && response.data.message === 'Session active') {
          setIsAuthenticated(true);
          setUsername(response.data.user_id);  // Set the username or user_id from the response
        } else {
          setIsAuthenticated(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Session check failed:', error);
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
    };
    checkSession();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <CustomNavbar
          theme={theme}
          setTheme={setTheme}
          isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
          setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated}
          username={username}
          setUsername={setUsername}
        />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login theme={theme} setTheme={setTheme} setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated} setUsername={setUsername} />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup theme={theme} setTheme={setTheme} setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated} setUsername={setUsername} />} />
          {/* <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated} setUsername={setUsername} />} /> */}
          <Route path="/" element={
            <PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}>
              <Home />
            </PrivateRoute>
          } />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={
            <PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}>
              <Dashboard />
            </PrivateRoute>
          } />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

login.jsx This is my login code added if required.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './login.css';

const Login = ({ theme, setTheme, setIsAuthenticated, isAuthenticated }) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const [errormessage, setErroMessage] = useState('');
  const [sessionStatus, setSessionStatus] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        credentials: 'include'
      });

      const result = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        setSessionStatus(result.session_status);
        navigate('/');
      } else {
        console.error('Login failed:', result);
        setErroMessage(result.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={`login-page ${theme}`}>
        <div className="login-container">
          <div className="login-form">
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Username"
                  {...register('username', { required: 'Username is required' })}
                />
                {errors.username && <span className="error">{errors.username.message}</span>}
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <input
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  {...register('password', { 
                    required: 'Password is required',
                    minLength: { value: 6, message: 'Password must be at least 6 characters long' }
                  })}
                />
                {errors.password && <span className="error">{errors.password.message}</span>}
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                {errormessage && <div className="error-message">{errormessage}</div>}
                {sessionStatus && <div className="session-status">{sessionStatus}</div>}
                <a href="/forgotpassword" className="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="login-welcome">
            <h2>Welcome to Login</h2>
            <p>Don't have an account?</p>
            <Link to="/signup">
              <button className="sign-up-button">Sign Up</button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;

This is the error i am getting every time when i clicked on logout
